# collapse recyclerview with different view types

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

So, I have a recyclerview with multiple view types. I'm using this  [link](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e) to generate my adapter class, becauseI have multiple viewholders in my recyclerview. Now the problem I have is with collapsing certain items inside it. What I want is whenever I press
the green toggle, item 2 and 3 in the list should collpase but 4,5,6 should remain upon,unless you have clicked on the green item ofcourse. I tried many ways to approach this but I  can not achieve this with the link provided. Is there any way I can achieve this?
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click collapsing button you have to remove your collapsing data from your all source list. When you remove your item from your list recyclerView automatically animates it.After that when you want to show it again you have to insert it your list again and notify that.RecyclerView also animates again when you insert it. There is a useful link here for inserting and removing special data from recyclerView https://medium.com/@suragch/updating-data-in-an-android-recyclerview-842e56adbfd8